# Может, синонимизировать метки [beautiful-soup] и [bs4]?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [bs4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bs4) (460 вопросов) с таким описанием:

> Используйте данную метку если Ваш вопрос связан с библиотекой Beautiful Soup для Python

Также есть метка, собственно [beautiful-soup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup) (898 вопросов), с описанием библиотеки *Beautiful Soup*:

> Beautiful Soup – это Python библиотека для синтаксического разбора файлов HTML/XML, которая может преобразовать даже неправильную разметку в дерево синтаксического разбора.

Может быть, их надо синонимизировать?

Comment: С версиями не очень хорошо обычно иметь синонимы к основному названию. Например, если появится [bs5], такую метку тоже будет нужно синонимизировать к основной? Как потом различать [bs4] и [bs5]? Тем не менее, на enSO [bs4] и [beautiful-soup] синонимы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но в описании [bs4] нет вообще ни какого упоминания версии.

Comment: Упоминания нет. Но цифра означает именно версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синонимизировал. Авось подход enSO не подведёт.