# Запросы о синонимизации и их детализация

Tags: обсуждение, синонимы-меток, мета

Последнее время Мета сайт поглотили запросы на синонимизацию меток, см. [синонимы-меток](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba). Это в целом хорошо, т.к. делает содержимое сайта более структурированным. Но мне бы хотелось, чтобы авторы запросов чуть более подробнее подходили к теме. В частности, имея под боком большой [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/), можно подсмотреть существующие синонимы там и сослаться на это для укрепления версии о необходимости синонимизации/объединения меток.

Конечно, возможны ситуации, когда enSO "не прав" и мы желаем сделать по-своему. Но как минимум рассмотреть вариант другого сайта стоит. И в таких случаях объяснить, почему не стоит идти по стопам enSO. Можно также заглянуть на братские сайты SO: [на испанском](https://es.stackoverflow.com), [на португальском](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), [на японском](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) и посмотреть синонимы меток там.

Иногда автору запроса ситуация может показаться очевидной, но шанс, что читатели его не поймут - всегда ненулевой, поэтому лучше раскрывать пожелание несколько подробнее, за исключением каких-то уж очень тривиальных случаев, покрываемых словарным переводом с английского на русский и наоборот.

Answer (score 10):

### Как написать хорошее предложение о синонимизации меток

#### Шаг 1: Подумайте, нужны ли синонимы?

Действительно ли найденные вами метки - синонимы?

- Прочитайте их описания (если они есть).
- Посмотрите, как их используют в вопросах. Не перекладывайте эту работу на читающих ваше предложение, раз уж предлагаете, сделайте сами.
- Проверьте, что ваши синонимы не являются [мета-метками](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/), мета-метки вообще нужно сжигать.

#### Шаг 2: Подумайте, можете ли вы справиться самостоятельно?

- Если вопросов по одной из меток мало, то вы можете вручную заменить её на более популярную.
- Если у вас хватает репутации и есть 5 баллов по метке, то вы можете [предложить синоним метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) на [странице синонимов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

#### Шаг 3: Придумайте хороший заголовок.

В заголовке должна содержаться суть предложения. Кликбейты лишние (**UPD**: как оказалось, не всё так однозначно. На enSO например кликбейты и смешные заголовки [легализовали](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295586/21103898). Правда, это обычно касается удаления меток, но и с синонимами пусть тоже будет).

Лучше всего использовать шаблоны.

**Шаблоны для заголовков:**

- > Надо синонимизировать метки [метка1] и [метка2].
- > Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [название темы]

**Хорошо:**

- > Надо синонимизировать метки [301] и [http-status-code-301]
- > Надо синонимизировать метки на темы [перевод] и [локализация]

**Плохо:**

- > Предлагаю объединить некоторые метки

#### Шаг 4: Приведите информацию

- Какие метки вы считаете синонимами **и почему**.
- Какую метку, по вашему мнению, нужно сделать основной **и почему**.
- Если это два термина на русском и английском, то посмотрите, какой больше используется в основной части вопросов. Так можно определить, стоит ли делать английскую метку основной, или отдать предпочтение метке на русском. Подробнее здесь: [Язык меток: русский или английский?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/%d0%af%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b)
- Сколько вопросов по приведённым меткам и есть ли у них описания.

Не заставляйте читающих ваше предложение искать всю эту информацию за вас.

#### Шаг 5: Метки в вашем посте-предложении

Предложение о синонимизации меток должно содержать метки [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) [метки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8) [синонимы-меток](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba). Если речь идёт о метках на мете, то добавьте ещё метку [мета](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0).

#### Шаг 6: Следите, что вам говорят в комментариях

Участники пишут что-то в комментариях не просто так! Не игнорируйте комментарии и ответы на ваш пост, там может быть важная информация от тех, кто разбирается в теме и отвечает по метке.

#### Шаг 7: После синонимизации попросите модератора повесить красную метку

И это не обязательно [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)! Может, это будет другая метка, например [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) или [статус-отложено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Это нужно для удобной сортировки предложений о синонимизации.

#### Примеры: как делать надо и как нет

**Хорошо**:

- [Синонимизировать [telegram] и [телеграм]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12929/) - вся информация есть (какая метка - основная, количество вопросов по меткам, наличие описания).
- [Надо синонимизировать [таблицы]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12885/) - тоже вся информация есть.
- [Может, синонимизировать метки [beautiful-soup] и [bs4]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12873/) - даже цитата из описания есть.
- [Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [таймер]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12976/) - есть вся информация, поэтому синонимизация чуть ли не сразу была проведена.

**Плохо**:

- [Предлагаю объединить некоторые метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7106/532877) - плохо почти по всем пунктам. Заголовок непонятный, в первоначальной версии ещё и сомнительные синонимы были. В вопросе просто куча похожих меток, часть их которых действительно оказались синонимами. Никаких пояснений и объяснений.
- [Синонимизировать метки на тему [кодогенераторы]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12958/) - с одной из меток всего 3 вопроса, можно было самому справиться, так как у участника больше 2k, (править без проверки может). Ну и идея создавать третью метку сомнительна.
- [Надо синонимизировать метку [linked-list]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12957/) - это вообще [переименование-метки](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8), к тому же ещё и бессмысленное.
- [Синонимизация [тайл]ов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12883/) - не указано, в какую сторону делать синонимами. И опять-таки, можно было справиться самому, с одной из меток всего 4 вопроса. И про [tilemap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilemap) можно было бы тоже попытаться разобраться, что это и зачем существует.

Comment: Как вы их назвали "туманные" заголовки - часть лора SO, используемая на вопросах об удалении меток или синонимах, там где это очевидно.

Comment: "... стоит ли делать английскую метку основной, или отдать предпочтение метке на русском." - см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/37/507426

Comment: @wchistow добавил эту ссылку в ответ.

Comment: Подробнее про каламбуры в запросах на синонимы: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295586/488443

Comment: @Kromster дописал про это.

Comment: @Nofate спасибо за ссылку, добавил её в пост.